# Downloading a large file from GridFS using C# gives Sort exceeded memory limit error

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, gridfs

I am using the following code to download a file from GridFS.

```
var stream = await this.gridFsBucket.OpenDownloadStreamAsync(new ObjectId(fileId));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command find failed: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort exceeded memory limit of 33554432 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting..
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessResponse(ConnectionId connectionId, CommandMessage responseMessage)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocolAsync[TResult](IWireProtocol`1 protocol, ICoreSession session, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadOperationExecutor.ExecuteAsync[TResult](IRetryableReadOperation`1 operation, RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ReadCommandOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSForwardOnlyDownloadStream`1.GetFirstBatchAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSForwardOnlyDownloadStream`1.GetSegmentAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSForwardOnlyDownloadStream`1.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StreamCopyOperationInternal.CopyToAsync(Stream source, Stream destination, Nullable`1 count, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.FileResultExecutorBase.WriteFileAsync(HttpContext context, Stream fileStream, RangeItemHeaderValue range, Int64 rangeLength)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.FileStreamResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, FileStreamResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|27_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I tried to find a way to enable `allowDiskUse` to true for GridFS but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

You are perhaps missing the indexes that drivers are supposed to create automatically.

- Ensure you are using the most recent driver release.
- Upload another file to the same GridFS bucket. You can delete the file immediately afterward.
- Check for index presence manually. See [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst) under "indexes" for what should exist.

Comment: Indexes are created as expected in [this](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst#indexes). This error is thrown even when the required indexes are present.

Comment: In that case use command monitoring to identify the problematic query, add to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I Used DownloadAsBytes.

The error was solved by Deleting the Database then letting the GridFs create the Database again.